# Drag & mouse click at the same time

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, mouse, mouseevent

How to drag & mouse click at the same time?

Can I combine the mousedrag&mouse clicked events? I would like to be able to click while moving the mouse.

the events on their own:

```
private void formMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{                                              
}  

private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       a=a-1000;
       jTextField1.setText(a+"");       
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "combine"?  Do you only want to listen for click events if the user is dragging the mouse? Do you only want one listener method to listen for both kinds of events?

Comment: The first one (being able to listen for click events while the user is dragging the mouse)

Comment: By default, a drag dictates that a mouse button is down.  You "could" use a MouseMoitionListener to detect mouseMoved events, but this will require you to determine the context of the movement